# :selected is not working when used with collection_select in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to use :selected attribute in order to preset the value in the form .Unfortunately its getting to set to blank value .

```
 <div class="field">
    <%= form.label :discrepancy_id, 'Failure Category' %>
    <%= form.collection_select :discrepancy_id, Discrepancy.group(:category), :id, :category, {:selected => (Discrepancy.all.select('id').where("category LIKE 'AVOD%'").first)}, :class => 'failure-category', :required => true%>
  </div>
```

The query works fine in rails console:

```
Discrepancy.all.select('id').where("category LIKE 'AVOD%'").first
```

It doesnot work with :selected attribute .
Note : If I specify the id value (i.e :selected = > 1 ) works fine but (:selected => Discrepancy.all.select('id').where("category LIKE 'AVOD%'").first) not working
I dont undertand whats going wrong? Please let me know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line returns an object, just because you use select the id doesn't change the fact that you get an object back.

```
Discrepancy.all.select('id').where("category LIKE 'AVOD%'").first
```

you however need just the id

```
Discrepancy.where("category LIKE 'AVOD%'").first.id
```